# Ajax not sending info to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get some information from my php code when clicking on a button, but it doesn't connect to php.

front page is displayed in index.php
index.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>

    <title>Account Panel</title>
    </head>


    <div "getInfos">
    <h2>In this section you can get your inforrmation</h2>
    <button id="getNameBtn">Get Your Name!</button>
    <span id="getNameSpan"> something must come here</span>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

javascript codes and ajax are in 
functions.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getNameBtn").live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        data:JSON.stringify({taskid = 1}),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },

        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById('getNameSpan').innerHTML = response;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error Ajaxing");
        }

        });

   });
```

and php in serverside is some simple thing like this:

handler.php:

```
    <?php

    echo('Ajax successful!');

    ?>
```

Comment: are you getting error alert ? also try to dump the `response` from `success` callback to console, to see what is outputted

Comment: What response you get, when you run the code ? Do you get "Error Ajaxing" in the response

Comment: Always check your console for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not close the document ready function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#getNameBtn").live('click', function() {
            $.ajax({ 
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'handler.php',
              data:JSON.stringify({taskid = 1}),
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },

              success: function(response) {
                document.getElementById('getNameSpan').innerHTML = response;
              },
              error: function() {
                alert("Error Ajaxing");
              }
            });

       });
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Additionally, `$.on` should be used instead of `$.live` since `live` is deprecated.

Comment: @Rutwick you are right, but he is using jquery older version. so deprecation is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`data:JSON.stringify({taskid = 1}),`

shoulde be

`data:JSON.stringify({taskid: 1}),`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should better use a newer jquery version.

There is at least one error in your Code:

```
data:JSON.stringify({taskid = 1})
```

The json should read

```
{taskid : 1}
```

Use a colon, not an equal sign. Not sure that it is true for your jQuery version, but usually data can be attached as json object already, so the whole line should work so:

```
data: {taskid : 1},
```

And the data is then visible as POST data in the PHP page. Note that the live() function is deprecated since 1.7. You can use

```
$("#getNameBtn").click(function(){...});
```

instead. Moreover, I don't think you need the headers in your request.

Answer (score 0):

First important change you need to do, use `$.on` instead of `$.live`, since the latter is deprecated. Another thing you should check, if the `handler.php` file is at the same level as your JS/HTML file. It could be that the file is not reachable from your code. Here is what you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getNameBtn").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'handler.php',
            data: { call: 'myAjax', taskid : 1 },
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#getNameSpan').html(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error Ajaxing");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in the PHP file, you can check for the `call` key:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['call'] == 'myAjax') {
        echo $_POST['taskid'];
        exit;
    }
?>
```

That `exit` is really important.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file that returns JSON you should also set the header to JSON.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json"); //Above all HTML and returns
```

And the true answer to your problem has already been answered.